# Would it be possible to have hair/fur that change color quickly (Aka "Chameleon hair/fur")?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology

I was thinking about replacing melanin with an electrochromic organic material. Basically when you pass a small current in an [electrochromic material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochromism), it change color depending on the current.

Would this be feasible? If not, do you know a way it could?

Comment: You should also consider the possibility of transparent fur (e.g. Polar Bear) so that you could replicate other animals abilities' to change skin color and have it be visible.

Comment: Alternatively, consider that not all mammals have hair (e.g. Whales, Naked Mole Rat) and a hairless mammal could also more easily use similar strategies to those that exist in the animal kingdom already (such as by flushing the skin with blood, like humans and lizards do).